# How to import custom EL function in JSPX?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jspx

It seems that I can't use something like

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/my.tld" prefix="my"%>
```

because it is not a valid xml markup for jspx.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Use this tag attribute in your JSP document: `xmlns:my="urn:jsptld:/WEB-INF/tlds/my.tld"` (TLDs should be in tlds subdirectory of WEB-INF).

Comment: Thank you for answer sir but when I tried this but was not still able to access my functions. I'll be posting my codes in a while...